# Errror which crashed the my hosted node.js server file which is run on fore erver command

Tags: node.js

My node.js server file which is hosted on a server is used by my various applications like mobile apps and desktop app.

At some time my server file which is run through forever command crashes and my whole front end system goes down. Why does the server file crash?

```
Type Error: Cannot read property 'fragmentedOperation' of null
    at Receiver.endPacket (C:\Users\root\Desktop\Server\windowsnodefiles\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node_modules\socket\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:247:18)
    at Receiver.finish (C:\Users\root\Desktop\Server\windowsnodefiles\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:483:12)
    at Receiver.<anonymous> (C:\Users\root\Desktop\Server\windowsnodefiles\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:451:33)
    at Receiver.add (C:\Users\root\Desktop\Server\windowsnodefiles\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:95:24)
    at Socket.realHandler (C:\Users\root\Desktop\Server\windowsnodefiles\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:800:20)
    at emit One (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readability (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at Nonreactive (net.js:547:20)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #2
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: The error mentions about the file Receiver.js and the line number with column number of error prone code. You can check those lines of codes for debugging. Apart from that, stackoverflow users cannot just answer useful answers blindly without knowing what those code are.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using browserSync library then you can check this [link](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/366)

> rollback the browserSync version to ^2.6.4 and it works

or try updating your socket.io package as per this [link](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2442)

> Please check if your issue is fixed with the latest release